# angular server side build error not able to find error

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, build, server-side-rendering

I am using angular 8 project with server side build and I am getting error in server side. The issue is here I am not able to find the error comes from which file it is showing error from build file which is very large So I cannot identify the error comes from where. Please let me know how to make server side build so error show from source code not from build.

Error :

```
ERROR { TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
        at Object.updateDirectives (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:95468:326)
        at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:77487:21)
        at checkAndUpdateView (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76499:14)
        at callViewAction (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76865:21)
        at execComponentViewsAction (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76793:13)
        at checkAndUpdateView (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76506:5)
        at callViewAction (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76865:21)
        at execEmbeddedViewsAction (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76822:17)
        at checkAndUpdateView (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76500:5)
        at callViewAction (httpdocs/dist/server/main.js:76865:21)
```

Comment: Have you tried to build without server side? You should get an error message in the browsers console to.

Comment: @Duki I am getting error only on server side no browser side. Is there any way to run application without bundling the code on server side.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practise to check if the object whose properties you are using is not null or undefined. So, if you can, then try this approach:

Suppose you have an object named `variable` (maybe string, Object, Array...). Wherever your have used `variable.length`, add `variable &&` before it.

For example, if you have

```
if(variabe.length > 0){
   //Do something
}
```

Use

```
if(variable && variabe.length > 0){
   //Do something
}
```

It might help you.

Comment: Actually I am not able to find the file from where error comes from. Is there any way to run application without bundling the code on server side.